# In pgfplots - > How to get a horizontal bargraph, stack with two values, while result is not square

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

This may sound very confusing, but basically, i would like to get a stack bargraph, which contains one bar, that consists of two separate values. Furthermore, if possible, can i have the result not as the standard square, but more of a recangle shrunk down to fit the size of the bar?

Comment: What you try so far?  Do you looks examples in `pgfplots` documentation, pages 97 -- 99?

Comment: Please show a drawing sketch or something similar (Paint, Gimp etc.). Or even better, a minimal example that can be worked on and tried out.

Answer (score 1):

Your question surely could be worded more clearly. If I understood correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    legend style={
        legend columns=1,
        anchor=south,
        draw=none
    },
    ytick=data,
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    tick label style={font=\small},
    legend style={font=\small},
    label style={font=\small},
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    bar width=6mm,
    xlabel={x axis},
    yticklabels={y axis},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=25,
    % area legend,
    y=10mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
]
\addplot[green,fill=green] coordinates
% Amount A
{(10,0)};
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates
% Amount B
{(25,0)};
\legend{Amount A, Amount B}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which would render the following output:

[image: stacked bar graph]